# python regex to catch text between innermost brackets

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that extracts text between a starting and an ending char (open and close bracket in my example) if and only if such text is made up of a specified number of words.

I'm using this regex (really simple) that works in this case.

```
 re.findall("(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))", "bla bla (bla bla) bla bla")
 actual output: ['bla bla']
```

But fail in this:

```
re.findall("(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))", "bla bla (bla ( bla bla) bla bla")
 
actual output: ['bla ( bla bla']
desired output: [' bla bla']
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to extend the `(.*?)` parts in order to search by a condition.
Imagine to catch all the text between two brackets if the text between them is composed by two words

```
re.findall("(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))", "bla bla (bla ( bla bla) bla bla (bla bla bla) bla")
desired output: [' bla bla']
```

Can you help me?

Comment: For your 2nd point, instead of allowing all character ( .* ) between the parentheses, you can exclude "(" by using [^\(]* : re.findall("(?<=\()([^\(]*?)(?=\))", "bla bla (bla ( bla bla) bla bla"). Try it on your last example too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match 2 words that do not contain chars `(` and `)` between `(...)` you can use a capture group to get the inner value:

```
\((\s*[^\s()]+\s+[^\s()]+\s*)\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\s*` Match optional leading whitespace chars
  - `[^\s()]+`  Match 1+ non whitespace chars without `(` and `)`
  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars between the words
  - `[^\s()]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars without `(` and `)`
  - `\s*` Match optional trailing whitespace chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t71OKX/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\((\s*[^\s()]+\s+[^\s()]+\s*)\)"

s = ("bla bla (bla bla) bla bla\n"
            "bla bla (bla ( bla bla) bla bla\n"
            "bla bla (bla ( test5 ) bla bla\n"
            "bla bla (bla ( test6 test7 test8 ) bla bla")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['bla bla', ' bla bla']
```